# How to check value by name deep nested at an array of object

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I'm on angular project and need to do a pipe that filtering data base on value that deep nested on object at array of objects

**Let's show you an example:** 
I need to return only the data with `name` of value equal `one` or what ever.

```
[
  ...
  {
    "attributes": [
      ...
      {
         ...
         name: 'one' // I need to return true if name has value of one and false if not
         ...
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried `filter` but I access an arr of obj with it so I couldn't or don't know what next?.

**My pipe code for reference**:

```js
  transform(value: any[], ...args: any[]): any {
    return value.every( variation => variation.attributes ); // what next?
  }
```

Comment: How many levels do you have ? Unknown ?

Comment: It's up there on json code with `name` but anyway two I guess array of obj inside every object at an array

Answer (score 0):

I will be something like that:

```
transform(lists: any[]): any {
   return lists
    .map(item => item['attributes'] && item['attributes'].find(attribute => attribute['name'] === 'one'))
    .find(item => !!item)
}
```

It will return the first data (I don't know what do you mean by data) with name 'one'